# Can't reach remote desktop anymore with RDC

Tags: windows, connection, remote, desktop

We have a 2 backup machines that we use to manage via Remote Dektop Connection; Suddenly one of them can not be reached anymore by RDC. The other one is still accessible.
I can ping the first one, even managed to restart it with the shutdown /r /computer commandline, but no way to access it on RDC.

Any idea about what could have happened? How else could I take control over these remote servers ? The inaccessible one  runs Windows Server 2008, the other one runs Windows 7.

EDIT: We got an operator to directly log on the machine at the datacenter, turns out that the firewall configuration wasn't allowing remote access. We have no idea what happened, maybe a windows Update set the firewall configuration back to a more secure one ?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools for remote managing Windows Servers, even without remote desktop connections. The most valuable means to troubleshoot such kind of problems are remote event viewer access, remote registry access, remote administrative file shares (`\\server\C$`) and a remote command line provided by [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). Of course, the use of those tools would depend on the firewall configuration of the destination machine not blocking the appropriate traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Royal TS.  Very nice too!!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here.

Comment: That tool seems really effective and rich. But as I expected I couldn't connect to the machine, the RPC server turned down for some reason I don't know. So I guess it's going to be hard to remotely turn on the remote procedure call server...

Comment: Silly question, but let me ask it anyway, remote access is turned on for that machine?